# Python: How to combine two dictionaries in python such that the resultant contains key as the value from the first

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries as follows:

```
mydictionary_1 = {1:'apple',2:'banana'}
mydictionary_2 = {1:50,2:30}
```

The resultant dictionary should be such that it takes the key as the value of first dictionary.

```
 Result_dictionary= {'apple':50, 'banana':30}
```

Comment: Just a note, dictionaries don't have an order, so your result dictionary may be a bit scrambled

Comment: `{mydictionary_1[k]: v for k, v in mydictionary_2.items()}`

Comment: @vaultah, your answer was first and was most helpful, try posting it as answer rathar than a comment, I would have marked ur one's as resolved, in comments i can't mark....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension using the values of the first dictionary as the keys of the resulting dictionary. This assumes all *keys* of the first are present in the second `dict`

```
{v: dict2[k] for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

you can also add a check for the presence of the keys in the second dictionary

```
{v: dictionary_2[k] for k, v in dictionary_1.items() if k in dictionary_2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through one of the dictionaries and check if the value for a key in mydictionary_1 exists in mydictionary_2.

You can achieve this using python's dictionary comprehension -

```
Result_dictionary = { v:mydictionary_2[k] for k,v in mydictionary_1.iteritems() if k in mydictionary_2.keys()}
```

To see how this list comprehension is working you can even use general for loop to loop through each key, value pair in mydictionary_1

```
for key,value in mydictionary_1.iteritems():
  if key in mydictionary_2.keys():
    Result_dictionary[value]=mydictionary_2[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

***Dictionary comprehension*** is an ideal solution for this one, as previously mentioned. Here is a ***for loop*** example:

```
def combine_dictionaries(dict1, dict2):
    result_dictionary = {}
    for key in dict1.keys():
        result_dictionary[dict1[key]] = dict2[key]
    return result_dictionary

combine_dictionaries({1:'apple', 2:'banana'}, {1:50, 2:30})

>>>{'apple': 50, 'banana': 30}
```

This assumes all values of the dict1 are present in the dict2.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dict_cross_match(dict1, dict2):
    new_dict = {}
    for item in dict1.keys():
        if item in dict2.keys():
            new_dict[dict1[item]] = dict2[item]
    return new_dict

mydictionary_1 = {1:'apple',2:'banana'}
mydictionary_2 = {1:50,2:30}
print(dict_cross_match(mydictionary_1, mydictionary_2))
```